# What is the issue in this PHP code to connect on localhost XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, connection

*The error is:*
**Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'moomen'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

**Code is:**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "moomen";
$password = "9124279123";
$dbname = "ecocaa";
try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$servername", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
echo "Connected successfully";

} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Either the user does not exist, or the password is wrong, or the mysql user account is not setup for access from "localhost". We can't tell, since we don't know your mysql user config, and we don't know your password.

Comment: no, I'm sure the data is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a problem in your code
In the dbname you have used server name, change the code it will work.

Comment: can you explain more, please

Comment: Oh, you are right, thank you @Subhashis Pandey it's working now

Comment: Oh, you are right, thank you @SubhashisPandey it's working now